# Как реализовать Dependency Injection?

Tags: php, ооп

Цель: получить что-то вроде этого (псевдокод):

```
class Validation
{
    private $db; 
    public function __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function checkUnique()
    {
        $this->db->countUsers();
    }
}
```

Условная реализация:

```
class DB
{
    // переменные для подключения к БД:
    // protected: host, login, db, password

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Возвращение объекта подключения к БД DBConnect
    }

    public function checkDouble($table, $column, $email)
    {
        // тут мы сходили в базу
        return $table.'-'.$column.'-'.$email;
    }
}

class Validation
{
    public function checkUnique($table, $column, $email)
    {
        $count = (new DB())->checkDouble($table, $column, $email);
    }
}

$obj = new DB();
$val = new Validation();
$check = $val->checkUnique('users', 'mail', 'email@domain.com');
```

Я не очень понимаю что в конструктор Validation в моём случае передавать? Переменной $db здесь в Validation нет, а просто класс передать нельзя, например `public function __construct(DB)` пишет должна быть переменная. Как тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: `$obj = new DB();
$val = new Validation($obj);` ........ может тебе пойти книжку почитать лучше для начала? хотя бы https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/139127353/  - 500 страничек.........можно еще  https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137538198/  и https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33506422/   ...... и потом книги по паттернам. И тогда не придется задавать такие вопросы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня есть 2 из 3 перечисленных книг. Ну вопросы оставлять вроде не запрещено ещё тут...

Comment: Не запрещено. Но прочитав эти книги от корки до корки и внимательно их изучив - подобных вопросов просто не возникнет, потому что там всё описано и продемонстрированно. Особенно самый банальный факт - передача аргументов в конструктор да и вообще в любой метод

Answer (score 1):

di - это инструмент внедрения зависимостей их уже существует довольно много со своими особенностями, есть в psr немного инфы https://github.com/php-fig/container

У тебя ответ записан в псевдо коде.

```
class Validation
{
   private $db; 
   public function __construct(DB $db)
   {
       $this->db = $db;
   }
   public function checkUnique()
   {
    $this->db->countUsers();
   }
}


$validation = new Validation(new DB());
$validation->checkUnique();

// но обычно при использование DI есть объект реализующий ContainerInterface (пусть будет $container) и пишется примерно так
$validation = $container->get(Validator::class);
$validation->checkUnique();
// Это был пример service locator.
```

Кстате у меня есть свой небольшой проект по реализации инструмента di https://github.com/smpl/mydi

Есть еще такое понятие как DIP (Dependecy Injection Principle) ну и еще это все базируется поверх агрегации и композиции https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)