# Когда стоит делать класс абстрактным?

Tags: php, ооп

Проект saas-сервис типа мегаплана. В голове есть приблизительная структура классов, например: работа с БД, работа с задачами, сервисный класс отвечающий за персональные настройки, валидатор данных, api.

**Вопрос:** по каким признакам можно определить что этот класс нужно сделать абстрактным а конкретные реализации делать уже в наследниках?

Например если есть несколько типов пользователей (бесплатный, тариф 1, тариф 2) стоит ли делать класс пользователей абстрактным и в нём уже задавать общие свойства пользователей а дальше уже делать их права разными?

Или что стоит вынести в абстракцию для класса работы с БД например?

Comment: Хм... а если пользователь захочет поменять тариф? Может сделать объект тарифный план и его включать в объект-пользователя (тогда можно будет менять лишь одну ссылку)? А вообще класс делают абстрактным, если вы не планируете создание объектов этого класса. Поэтому по тарифам мой ответ: да, стоит. С базой данных обычно не прибегают к абстрактным классам, только если у вас нет гигантского количества инстансов базы данных, соединение с которыми вам нужно разруливать, используя какую-то логику, и логика требует, чтобы вы могли различать соединения одной группы серверов, от другой.

Comment: @cheops ну имеется ввиду не наметрво же привязывать а задавать общие свойства что у пользователя есть тариф, email, и другие свойства.

`класс делают абстрактным, если вы не планируете создание объектов этого класса`

ну это не основная причина правда? )) Класс делают абстрактным когда нужен каркас. Вопрос: в каких случаях нужен каркас?

Comment: Когда вы планируете заложить полиморфизм, т.е. вам нужно, чтобы объекты наследующие абстрактному классу отвечали на одни и те же методы и эти методы назывались у всех одинаково. Например, у вас есть коллекция пользователей, у каждого разный тарифный план, но вам нужно подсчитать общую сумму дохода за месяц со всей группы. Если вы заложите в абстрактный класс метод price, его будут обязаны реализовать все наследники и вам можно не париться об логике подсчета, скидках и т.п. Абстрактный класс гарантирует, что не появится тарифного плана без метода price.

Comment: На самом деле как cheops написал "когда вы планируете заложить полиморфизм". Но я бы хотел сделать акцент вот на чём: когда делается проект по какому-либо ТЗ, в котором написано что где с чем и почём планируется быть, то вы можете не час и не два просидеть над мыслями как это должно быть реализовано. Надо будет посидеть и нарисовать схемы что где будет и что с чем должно взаимодействовать. Потом всё это поделие смять и выкинуть и заново писать. А потом исправлять, а потом еще раз выкинуть. То есть слёту код никто не пишет. И  основываясь на чётком конечном продукте и реализации. Просто вот..)

Comment: @cheops понятно ну кстати это для интерфейсов я обязан сделать реализацию всех методов, а для абстрактного класса не обязательно

Comment: @fosh4455 если методы абстрактные - то обязан

Comment: @fosh4455 в интерфейсе вы не можете реализовать метод. А в абстрактном классе можно.. Вообще интерфейс описывает поведение класса.

Comment: @KryTer_NexT ну я пока ещё не пронял фишку интерфейсов, поэтому пока не думаю о них...

Comment: @Abyx речь о языке PHP

Comment: Не стоит пытаться сделать окончательный дизайн сразу. Это всегда итерационный процесс. В самом начале абстрактные классы совсем не нужны. Вот когда у вас будет ядро системы и будут тесты, вот после этого вы сможете сделать рефакторинг.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вопрос: по каким признакам можно определить что этот класс нужно
>   сделать абстрактным а конкретные реализации делать уже в наследниках?

В самом вопросе уже имеется ответ. Когда имеется необходимость в полиморфизме (один интерфейс — множество реализаций), тогда стоит подумать о создании абстрактного класса (в роли интерфейса, зависит от ЯП), где будут указаны основные методы для работы с данными. И в зависимости от типа данных, уже создаются дочерние классы с конкретными реализациями под них.

Comment: Спасибо. Полиморфизм для меня пока остаётся самым сложно-понимаемым принципом ООП в отличие от инкапсуляции и наследования. Я не уверен что правильно его понимаю, а значит не могу определить когда надо использовать.

Comment: @fosh4455 с ним всё просто - если реализация действий будет разная от случая к случаю, то это и есть полиморф. Класс, описывающий общее для всех реализаций - абстрактный родитель, а сами реализации - потомки. Например, класс "хранилище" умеет сохранять и извлекать что-то откуда-то, но то может быть база, память, файл или удалённый ресурс. Методы save/load - пустые и в родителе, и сам он абстрактный т.к. оторван от реального контекста и расширяем в будущем.

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо, коммент кстати крутой, сразу понятнее стало

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактный класс стоит создавать только тогда когда ты понимаешь что объект данного класса создавать **не имеет смысла**, но все поля и методы которые находятся внутри нашего абстрактного класса **должны** быть у всех дочерних классов, то есть дочерний класс  **не может быть создан**  не имея нужных полей...

На счет тарифов, да можно. Так будет удобнее читать код и ориентироваться. 
А вот БД, я думаю только в том случае если у вас есть много других баз данных, и было бы удобно создать один абстрактный класс для инициализации методов типа `close()`, `connect()` и т.д. а внутри у дочерних классов имплементировать их под нужный вам БД. Но в этом случае, можно даже обойтись интерфейсом нежели чем абстрактным классом.

Comment: Суто в том, что сделав класс User наследником класса БД я получу возможность обращаться к родительскому классу для работы с БД, а если БД сделать отдельным независимым классом, то к нему придётся обращаться постоянно через что-то типа Dependency Injection как раз сегодня я вопрос задавал про это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706138/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-dependency-injection

Comment: То есть вы хотите сделать несколько реализаций БД для каждого пользователя? Для User-> UserDB, Moderator->ModeratorDB ? И унаследовать эти БД с основной но имплементируя только нужные методы?

Comment: нет класс с БД 1, остальные от него наследуются и используют его как раба, типа класс User говорит обнови мне данные юзера, класс событий говорит: дай мне события, или обнови события. Т.е. что бы им самим с БД не работать напрямую т.к. это нарушает принцип единой ответственности

Comment: А не проще ли просто иметь приватное поле БД у юзера? И взаимодействовать с ним? Или наследоваться от БД и открывать полный доступ ко всем методам БД как-то не правильно, конечно если в классе с БД все методы `public` или же `protected`..